# What font did Nintendo use for the freeze-frame titles in their newcomer trailers for the 2014 Super Smash Bros. games?

Tags: font-identification

In building up to the release of Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS and Wii U, Nintendo has been teasing the release of new playable characters by slowly releasing CGI trailers that feature [Badass Freeze-Frame Shots](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/discussion.php?id=15ncyealacdn8ki94rmwtmxj) (warning: TVTropes link) of the new fighters being, well, badass. Here's an example from the [E3 2013 trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmCVzjGVFy4) that introduced Mega Man as a playable character:

[image: Mega Man joins the battle!]

Ever since the first teaser dropped, there has been an influx of allegedly hilarious faked screenshots made to play on hopeful fans' emotions. Some are artistically impressive, but nobody seems to be able to get the font quite right.

**What font do the official teasers use?**

Answer (score 7):

It's [DF Gothic W10](http://www.fonts.com/font/dynacomware/df-gothic-japanese/w-10), a primarily Japanese font (with Latin characters too) by DynaComware. A license costs **$500** (wow!), probably because of how extensive the complete character set is. There doesn't seem to be a cheaper, latin-alphabet-only version available for purchase, so fulfilling your dreams of making totally accurate fake character announcements is probably going to get kind of pricey.

Here's a screenshot of the Fonts.com tryout tool, for comparison:

[image: Mega Man Joins the Battle!]

Finding it was kind of fun:

In Photoshop CC, I used the Perspective Crop tool to isolate a *mostly* un-perspective-warped version of the text from the [full size screencap](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/File:Megaman_Joins_The_Battle.png). Afterwards, I used the Quick Select tool and the "Refine Edge" tool (via `Select -> Refine Edge...`) to get the lettering into a style that most automated identifiers like. Here's what it looked like after I scaled it down:

[image: Mega Man Joins the Battle!]

I submitted that to both [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [WhatFontIs](http://www.whatfontis.com/). WhatTheFont didn't come through, but a page's worth of searching through WhatFontIs results led me to my answer, and perhaps the world of fakery is a little worse for it.

Comment: Very nice work! :)